# Yocto: oe_runmake failed, iMX6 Apalis

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I'm building a Yocto image for the first time in my life. I have some errors when I run **bitbake -k angstrom-lxde-image** (the demo Toradex distribution).
[First part of the log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Skp7K.png) and [second part of the log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDpOV.png).

It says a lot of things, e.g.

```
ERROR: imx-loader-native-git-r1 do_compile: oe_runmake failed
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -usb-1.0
MAkefile:27: recipe for target 'imx_usb' failed
```

I found some solution so far, but none of them seems to work...

Do you have any ideas how to resolve this problem?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you probably need to install `libusb-1.0-0-dev` package on your host.

Comment: Thanks Nayfe. Unfortunately it says it is already the newest version.

Comment: Can you provide recipe for imx_loader please? it probably misses DEPENDS to libusb for native part

Comment: ld founds libusb in native sysroot but it seems incompatible. Did you build it multiple times?

Comment: So in the imx-loader_git.bb there is a line 'DEPENDS = "libusb1-native"' How do you mean if I did build it mulitple times?

Comment: Maybe try to use a more recent version, it should be 
`DEPENDS = "libusb"` like latest version [here](http://git.toradex.com/cgit/meta-toradex-nxp.git/tree/recipes-devtools/imx-loader/imx-loader_git.bb)

Comment: It does not seem to work :(

Comment: you can contact toradex directly [here](https://www.toradex.com/community/)

Comment: You have to initiate your environment with [latest tag](http://git.toradex.com/cgit/toradex-bsp-platform.git/tree/default.xml?h=LinuxImageV2.8)

Comment: Is the error really `cannot find -usb-1.0`? I guess that it should be `cannot find -lusb-1.0`. Maybe there is some handling of flags which breaks it?